# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: jenkins for class: groovy.lang.Binding

Tags: jenkins, groovy

We're upgrading to a newer version of Jenkins (2.60.1) and a groovy script which was working in the previous Jenkins version (1.596/2) no longer works.

This is a Jenkins build project, which is parameterized and we're using a Groovy script to provide the choices for a Choice Provider (the Choice Provider is set to System Groovy Choice Parameter).

We're trying to get access to the Jenkins environment variables and do so like this (this is part of the Groovy script):

```
import hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty
import hudson.EnvVars

EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty prop = jenkins.getGlobalNodeProperties().get(EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.class)
EnvVars env = prop.getEnvVars()

def MY_VAR = env['MY_JENKINS_VAR']
```

However, I'm getting the following error when running the script:

```
Failed to execute script

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: jenkins for class: groovy.lang.Binding
at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:224)
```

It seems to me the "jenkins" reference is expected to be a built-in property provided by Jenkins or perhaps Groovy, but I can't find any information on what I need to do to make it accessible from the Groovy script.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As pointed out by @Jayan in another post, the solution was to do the following

```
import jenkins.model.*
jenkins = Jenkins.instance
```

Then I was able to do the rest of my scripting the way it was.

Answer (score 5):

Please double check that jenkins is not blocking this import. Go to script approvals and check to see if it is blocking it. If it is click allow.

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/

Comment: I'll check that when I get back to the office, but when I looked this afternoon there was nothing in the script approvals regarding the Groovy plugin.
Is the "jenkins" object provided by the Groovy plugin, or perhaps some other plugin?

Comment: I just checked the Jenkins build and after executing the Groovy script and getting the error (as reported above) I navigated to the In-process Script Approval page for the build and it doesn't show anything which needs approval (that applies to what I'm attempting). How am I supposed to get Jenkins build environment variables in my Groovy scripts?

Comment: @MarkHansen try toggling "Groovy Sandbox" to get different error messages. I believe that will also generate the request to use the script in the script approval section. I'm not 100% sure about that, i just know that I tried both with and without Sandbox checked, and eventually they showed up in the approval section. Make sure you're going to your Global Security Settings to get to it.

Answer (score 4):

in my case I have used `-` (Hyphen) in my script name in case of Jenkinsfile Library.
Got resolved after replacing `-` (Hyphen) with `_` (Underscore)

Comment: removed _uderscore and it worked thanks

Answer (score 2):

For me this problem occurred because I had a some invalid character in my Groovy script. In our case this was an extra blank line after the closing bracket of the script.