# Jenkins File Image Tag Parameters Not Working

Tags: docker, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment

I am attempting to auto tag my image through my jenkins pipeline and it isn't working as I would expect.   I am not good at pipelines and I am probably missing something elementary but any help would be appreciated.

I am hoping to use the built in `{env.BUILD_NUMBER}` variables that Jenkins provides.  I can echo out the build number but not pass it into my "imagebuilder" command.

Error:

```
[redFalconMonolith_RedFalcon-ZN46VHZ6UQAAXE632CFKUEXEBHIA52MJYXHIH6VUHK3MOAOQB64A] Running shell script
+ echo Build number: 108
Build number: 108
[Pipeline] sh
[redFalconMonolith_RedFalcon-ZN46VHZ6UQAAXE632CFKUEXEBHIA52MJYXHIH6VUHK3MOAOQB64A] Running shell script
+ echo Image Tag: gcr.io/redfalcon-186521/redfalcon-webserver-minimal:RedFalcon.108
Image Tag: gcr.io/redfalcon-186521/redfalcon-webserver-minimal:RedFalcon.108

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: KEY for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:242)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:288)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:292)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:268)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:268)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:46)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor411.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$101(SandboxContinuable.java:34)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.lambda$run0$0(SandboxContinuable.java:59)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:58)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:332)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Code:

```
def project = 'redfalcon-186521'
def  appName = 'redfalcon-webserver-minimal'
...

stage('Build Container') {
            steps {
                container('redfalcon-golang') {
                    sh "echo Build number: ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
                    sh "echo Image Tag: gcr.io/${project}/${appName}:${env.BRANCH_NAME}.${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
                    sh "imagebuilder -t gcr.io/${project}/${appName}:${env.BRANCH_NAME}.${env.BUILD_NUMBER} --build-arg GITHUB_OATH_KEY=$KEY -f DockerFiles/Dockerfile.local ."
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/a/47139746/3358570

Comment: Try using the Docker plugin instead.

Answer (score 0):

For reasons that I fully don't understand the problem was the my "KEY" Attribute (An Oauth Key that is used for Github) was not properly getting injected in the the jenkins slave at time of build.  It is in my dockerFile and when I ran it locally it existed so I don't know why it wasn't able to be read by Jenkins.

The solution that I came up with was to use the Jenkins Environment Variables in the system settings and it worked fine.

I wish I knew why it wasn't able to see it but I don't have time to diagnose it as the Jenkins Envionemnt Variables meets my needs (and isn't a major compromise).