# Jenkins Python execution groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: init for class

Tags: python, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to run Python script from Jenkins pipeline, but I am getting the below exception,

```
sh "python3.6 eks-tf-generate.py --cluster-count ..."

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: init for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:264)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:288)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:292)
```

I also tried installing, Pyenv Pipeline plugin and kept my python execution inside,

```
withPythonEnv('/usr/bin/python3.6')
```

still getting the same exception.

I am able to execute,

```
sh "python3.6 --version"
```

without any errors.

Jenkins ver. 2.150.3

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47064135/groovy-lang-missingpropertyexception-no-such-property-jenkins-for-class-groov