# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Jenkins for class: hudson

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-agent

I am trying to run a groovy script in Jenkins agent node to retrieve child jobs from a folder in Jenkins agent node. Here is the groovy script I tried:

I tried some SO answers and found [groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: jenkins for class: groovy.lang.Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47064135/groovy-lang-missingpropertyexception-no-such-property-jenkins-for-class-groov)

But this doesn't solve my problem.

Please find the code that I tried:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import jenkins.model.*

static main(args){

    def childJobFolder = "childJob"
    def childJobNameList = []

    def env = System.getenv()

    // Setting the environment properties to variables.
    def jenkinsUsername = env.UAT_JENKINS_MY_USER
    def jenkinsPassword = env.UAT_JENKINS_MY_PASS

    def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()

    // Getting the child job names from "childJob" folder
    Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(childJobFolder).allJobs.each{
        def childJobName = it.name.toString()
        if(childJobName.startsWith("job-")){
            childJobNameList.add(childJobName)
        }
    }

    println "\n" + "Child Jobs Available: " + childJobNameList + "\n"

}
```

Here is what I got in the console:

> Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Jenkins for class: hudson3067346520259876246
> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Jenkins for class: hudson3067346520259876246
> at hudson3067346520259876246.run(hudson3067346520259876246.groovy:17)
> Build step 'Execute Groovy script' marked build as failure

Can someone help me to fix this error?

Comment: There are two ways run script- each completely unrelated.  The "Jenkins" variable is only available for "System groovy scripts"(and pipelines)..   More at : https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found out the solution for this error. This is caused by running on plain groovy script instead of system groovy script. As Jayan said the Jenkins variables only available for System groovy scripts and not for plain groovy script. For that reason I could not load Jenkins instances from plain groovy script.